# Недопустимый термин в выражении

Tags: c#

Еще вчера программа работала. Почему теперь приводит к ошибке?

```
public static List<CurrencyInfo> AvailableCurrencyInfoList
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return <AvailableCurrencyInfoList>k__BackingField; //Ошибка CS1525  Недопустимый термин "<" в выражении 
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private set
    {
        <AvailableCurrencyInfoList>k__BackingField = value; //Ошибка    CS1525  Недопустимый термин "<" в выражении 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ну вот кого вы обманываете? Вы же эту программу декомпилировали и не можете скомпилировать обратно, да?

Выкиньте свой декомпилятор в мусорку и попробуйте воспользоваться другим. Например, ILSpy. *Такие* ошибки нормальный декомпилятор допускать не должен!